# rxbinding and click on right drawable

Tags: android, textview, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-binding

Is there a way to implement the on click listener on the right drawable of an EditText by using RxBinding?

The only thing I found is:

```
     RxTextView.editorActionEvents(mEditText).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<TextViewEditorActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(TextViewEditorActionEvent textViewEditorActionEvent) {
            int actionId = textViewEditorActionEvent.actionId();
            if(actionId == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

But in this event I can't find the info about the position of the click.

This is the way I did it by using RxJava:

```
public Observable<Integer> getCompoundDrawableOnClick(EditText editText, int... drawables) {
    return Observable.create(e -> {
        editText.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                for (int i : drawables) {
                    if (i == UiUtil.COMPOUND_DRAWABLE.DRAWABLE_RIGHT) {
                        if (event.getRawX() >= (editText.getRight() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[i].getBounds().width())) {
                            e.onNext(i);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // add the other cases here
            return false;

        });
    });
```

but I feel I'm reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching in the wrong place, if you need to check the touch event, use the base `View` touch event  using `RxView`, then apply your logic and filter out all non required touched, for having 'clicks' on your desired location (compound drawable).
I must admit I'm not sure I understands the for loop logic, you can use directly the `UiUtil.COMPOUND_DRAWABLE.DRAWABLE_RIGHT`, but anyhow followed your logic in this example:

```
public Observable<Object> getCompoundDrawableOnClick(EditText editText, int... drawables) {
        return RxView.touches(editText)
                .filter(motionEvent -> {
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        for (int i : drawables) {
                            if (i == UiUtil.COMPOUND_DRAWABLE.DRAWABLE_RIGHT) {
                                if (motionEvent.getRawX() >= (editText.getRight() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[i].getBounds().width())) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .map(motionEvent -> {
                    // you can omit it if you don't need any special object or map it to 
                    // whatever you need, probably you just want click handler so any kind of notification Object will do.
                });
    }
```